# Why do some English subtitles on youtube seem like poor romanisations of Korean?

Tags: pronunciation

Sometimes, a friend suggests suddenly that we would take a photo.
Then we have a gesture as follow :

Photo ? Why, without a reason ?

> (A) **사진 ? 아 왜 갑자기 ?**

When I watch a Korean drama in youtube, I can find a script :

> (B) **sahjhan oh I'm the cop jacket**

It is weird to me. In my thought, the following is more closer :

(C) sajin ? ah why gabjaki ?

To native English speaker, which one in (B), (C) is more closer to
(A) ?

Comment: Are you talking about the automatic subtitling that youtube can add?  It is using AI, and it is still very error-prone - and if you ask for English subtitles for Korean, it doesn't translate, it just chooses English words that sound somewhat similar to what it hears. "cop" sounds similar to 갑, "jacket" sounds similar to "자기", etc.

Comment: [Stack Exchange: Web Applications.](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Youtube's subtitling system isn't intended to add accurate *Romanisations* of (e.g.) Korean speech. As per gaeguri's comment, It seems in your case that you just have a Korean video that is being erroneously interpreted as English.

It is possible for youtube content creators to add *translations* to their videos, such that you'd see (for example) "A Photo? Why, without a reason?" in the English translation. It's also possible to perform automatic translation, and to add custom subtitles. It's only if someone has added a custom set of subtitles that you will see romanisation of Korean on youtube.